# How to make a JFrame button open another JFrame class in Netbeans?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jframe

I have a `JFrame` class and it was made in the design section on Netbeans. I am trying to make a log in button that takes closes the current frame and opens another, is there anyway I can do that?

I have tried:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
```

But I want it to be editable in the design section!

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556)

Answer (score 24):

Double Click the Login Button in the NETBEANS or add the Event Listener on Click Event (ActionListener)

```
btnLogin.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        this.setVisible(false);
        new FrmMain().setVisible(true); // Main Form to show after the Login Form..
    }
});
```

Comment: It's better to use `this.dispose()`  instead making it invisible as it will be still running without any use.

Comment: Yea Thats correct. But i thought that while the Form is dispose it may return to Main Function without showing the FrmMain.. OOPS...  I thought the Code will be Stopped then...

Comment: Great thought :) The code won't be stoped until executing all statements inside the actionPerformed method.

Answer (score 8):

```
new SecondForm().setVisible(true);
```

You can either use `setVisible(false)` or `dispose()` method to disappear current form.

Answer (score 6):

This link works with me: [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ml2b6XBunMI)

The answer posted before didn't work for me until the second click

So what I did is Directly call:

```
        new NewForm().setVisible(true);

        this.dispose();//to close the current jframe
```

Answer (score 1):

```
JFrame.setVisible(true);
```

You can either use `setVisible(false)` or `dispose()` method to disappear current form.