# How to get data from other JFrame to another JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

How do I get the same name after a successful login?

I have user class that set `user.setName` after verifying the user name and password from text file in login `JFrame` and `user.getName` in other frame to greet user in the main menu.

Comment: 1) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556) In this case, the log in should probably be displayed in a `JOptionPane` or a `JDialog`. 2) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's lots of different ways to do it, but basically it boils down to [Passing Information to a Method or a Constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html).

One thing you should do is to try and decouple the process.  Your "main menu" doesn't care where or how the user name is generated/gained, it only needs it.  Equally, your login process doesn't care what happens after the user is validated.

To that end, you should take the time to understand the [model-view-controller](https://blog.codinghorror.com/understanding-model-view-controller/) paradigm, you will see it a lot and will help you solve similar questions.

Basically, a "controller" will display the login view, the login view will gather the credentials and the this information will be feed back through the model for validation.  When successful, the controller can pass control on to the next controller which will actually display the "main menu", providing the login model as part of the information.

Again the "how" depends a lot on the overall solution, but you want to get to the point where you have the ability to change either or both the main menu and login windows and it won't have any affect on the other

You can also have a look at:

- [Open JFrame, only after successfull login verification with database. Using Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33487157/open-jframe-only-after-successfull-login-verification-with-database-using-ecli/33488721#33488721)
- [Java and GUI - Where do ActionListeners belong according to MVC pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26517856/java-and-gui-where-do-actionlisteners-belong-according-to-mvc-pattern/26518274#26518274)
- [Open a JPanel after pressing a button in a JFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27663306/open-a-jpanel-after-pressing-a-button-in-a-jframe/27663749#27663749)

for more details and ideas